# How to reduce a set of integers to a pre-defined size based on how the integers are clustered

Tags: statistics, algorithms

Imagine I have a collection of integers e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22, 44, 45, 46, 55, 56, 68, 69, 71, 200

I want to reduce these down to 5 numbers (they don't have to be integers). If I were to mark these on a number line there would be a group around 3 (1 - 5), another "group" at 22, another again at 45 (44, 45 and 46), one at 69.33 and another at 200 giving me the set of 3, 22, 45, 69.33 (made from the mean of 55, 56, 68 and 71) and 200.

If I only wanted 4 numbers I would get 3, 22, 200 and 56.75

If I wanted 3 numbers I would get 6.16 (from the set of 1 - 5 and 22), 56.75 and 200.

I'm obviously struggling to define what I am doing mathematically but I hope it is possible to discern the system from the sets I am providing.

I am not looking for an algorithm that will return my sets exactly as represented above! The point is it should show the points about which they are clustered.

The example set I provided does not show duplicates however duplicates are acceptable in the original set (but would not appear in the result set because you wouldn't have two clusters at the same location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all samples are as "clumpy" as yours. You seem to have a vague notion
instead of a specific definition of what you mean by a cluster. What if
your data were $(0, 5, 10, 11, 14, 21, 26, 29, 35, 40)?$ Also, you do not say anything about the *purpose* of your data summary. So I will answer
with a few much-used methods of 'summarizing data' (or 'reducing data dimensionality') that have general
application.

There is something in *exploratory data analysis* (EDA) called the **five number summary**. It consists of minimum, lower quartile, median, upper quartile, and maximum. These are the values used to make a basic 'boxplot' (one that does
not "identify" outliers).

For normal data, the goal is often to estimate the population mean $\mu$ and
variance $\sigma^2.$ Estimates are the sample mean $\bar X$ and the sample
variance $S^2.$ 
In this context, the pair $(\bar X, S^2)$ are called **sufficient statistics**
in the sense that they carry all information relevant to inference about $\mu$
and $\sigma^2,$ assuming the data are sampled at random from a normal population. For example, $\bar X$ and $S^2$ can be used to find 95% confidence intervals for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2.$ (But note that the sufficient statistics are not enough for
checking normality or independence of observations; one typically needs all of the data to do that.) Sometimes values such as $\bar X -2S, \bar X - S, \bar X, \bar X + S$. amd $\bar X + 2S$ are used to show the location and spread of
a sample.

One way to summarize much of the information in a large sample is to make
a **histogram** in which all bars are the same width. Then a list of the
centers of the bars (of info that specified such a list) and the number
of observations in each bin ('frequencies') can be used as an adequate
data summary for some purposes. Contingent on the number of bins, a 
histogram can show certain kinds of clustering.

I realize that the only one of these three suggestions that potentially relates to
clustering is the third. But considering them might convince you of the need to
have a well-defined purpose in mind before seeking to summarize data.

Finally, you might google 'cluster analysis' to see if there
is anything of use for you there, but cluster analysis is usually used for
multivariate data.

Comment: The cluster analysis proved particularly useful. I was interested in reducing a set of hexadecimal rgb colors. Many colors in the original palette were black to the human eye but varied slightly in their rgb values. My efforts in reducing the set usually resulted in the loss of a color that was obviously distinct.

Comment: Maybe something like a fixed cut-off for rgb values that are too small would work as well as cluster analysis and be simpler to implement.